# Recovering Mysql-server Mysql-client Mysql-common

Tags: mysql, dpkg

I had some issues with password of mysql therefore I removed mysql-server but when I tried to reinstall I still got those issue and was not able to login. I removed everything and purged the settings. Still above issue was regenerated. Finally I removed .cnf files and .cnf.falback file and even after this I got the same problem.So finally I removed mysql folder in /etc Now when I try to reinstall -

On running command of installing mysql-server Iam getting this-

```
update-alternatives: error: alternative path /etc/mysql/my.cnf.fallback doesn't exist
dpkg: error processing package mysql-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-common
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: I solved it, There was a confusion in Admin password and mysqlserver root password